# Getting a Broken Pipe while uploading an mp3 with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Keep getting a broken pipe after uploading a mp3 with paperclip to S3. What did i do wrong?

Model

```
  has_attached_file :mp3,
                :storage => :s3,
                :path => 'mp3/:class/:id/:style.:extension',
                :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                :bucket => 'cobras-production',
                :url => ':s3_domain_url'
```

Controller

```
 def create
  @track = Track.new(params[:track])
   if @track.save
    redirect_to(@track, :notice => 'Track was successfully created.')
   else
    render :action => "new"
   end
 end
```

Comment: Do you get the error if you upload a file that has no spaces, numbers or special characters? (see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419497/amazon-s3-only-accepting-files-with-no-spaces-no-numbers-in-the-title/4419580#4419580).

Comment: When try to upload a file called abc.mp3 i still get a broken pipe.

Comment: Any luck resolving this?

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be an issue with non us bucket locations.

I have 2 applications set up to run on heroku, and was running into the issue you mention. When i changed my bucket location to US the paperclip lib worked perfectly with exact same file.

Where you using singapore or tokyo as your bucket locaiton.

https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/issues/#issue/4

this explains the issue better

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth pointing out that buckets are not created automatically on-demand - you have to create them yourself. If you're using the aws-s3 gem, the command for that is

```
AWS::S3::Bucket.create("cobras-production")
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I chose a new (as of now) AWS region 'Oregon'.
When I switched back to US Standard for my bucket, I had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers: I had the same issue, the reason was in wrong time on my computer, which was included in request. Amazon's server compared my time and their, which caused an error.