# Amazon S3 only accepting files with no spaces, no numbers in the title?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

This is an odd question, but only commensurate with the strange behavior I'm seeing. My app is  Rails 3/Paperclip/S3.

Symptoms:

- All images are uploading regardless of their title.
- When uploading a .pdf or .doc, if the title has no spaces like my_doc.pdf, it uploads fine.
- When uploading a .pdf or .doc with spaces, such as My Doc.pdf, it fails, either with error `broken pipe` or by the file silently failing to upload to S3.
- When uploading a .pdf or .doc with numbers, such as mydoc20.pdf, it also fails as above.

I imagine there are two possible solutions to this problem.

1. Fix the `broken pipe` error directly (preferred method).
2. Automatically rename every uploaded file to remove spaces and numbers before it is saved to S3 - while not fixing it at the source, I imagine this would allay the issue.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in fixing 1 and/or 2.

---

### Code

```
# Upload.rb model
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :document,
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/docs/:style/:id/:basename.:extension"
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {:medium => "200x300>", :thumb => "100x150>" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/photos/:style/:id/:basename.:extension"

# s3.yml
development:
  bucket: dev_bucket_name
  access_key_id: dev_acc_key
  secret_access_key: dev_sec_key
production:
  bucket: my_production_bucket
  access_key_id: my_access_key_id
  secret_access_key: my_secret_key

# environment.rb is empty with regard to uploading.

# uploads_controller.rb
def edit
  @candidate = Candidate.find(current_user.user_type_id)
  render :layout => 'forms'
end

def update
  @candidate = Candidate.find(params[:id])
  if @candidate.update_attributes(params[:candidate])
    flash[:notice] = "Profile updated successfully."
    redirect_to :action => "show", :id => params[:id]
  else
    flash[:notice] = "There was an error updating your profile."
    render :action => "edit", :id => params[:id]
  end
end
```

I don't believe there are any methods involved. I almost hope there is something obviously wrong with my approach because that means it'll get fixed :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part two this should do it:

```
@s = "Really Important!*() Document version#123123.newest.pdf"
@s.gsub!(' ','_').downcase! #this will make everything lowercase and replace all spaces with underscores
@s.gsub!(/[^a-zA-Z._]+/,'') #this will remove all numbers and special characters except . and _
puts @s #prints "really_important_document_version.newest.pdf"
```

**Edit:** After some more research into paperclip I found the following: http://blog.wyeworks.com/2009/7/13/paperclip-file-rename

Check that link out, I believe it is what you are looking for.

**Edit 2:** In my initial read of your post I missed the part about pulling out numbers as well, I have modified the regulat expression code to account for that.

Comment: Austin, where and how would I need to put this code such that all attachments for the :pdf field are actually renamed before uploading to S3? There is no problem storing the data in my own database - they just fail to upload to the bucket for some reason.

Comment: Can you also post the code that handles the actual uploading process namely the controller and any methods in Upload.rb. I am thinking that the best place for the code I suggested is in a before_save filter in the model but I can't tell how your upload process works. How do the files actually get uploaded to S3?

Comment: Austin, thank you very much for your solution to option 2 - I'm still on the lookout for a fundamental solution to this strange problem. +1!